# Easiest way to get maximum transaction stack depth level

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, evm

When a contract causes an addresses code on the EVM, a stack depth counter is kept. I need this stack information as I am producing a EVM execution visualiser. 
This stack depth changes when a function is called.

I am currently getting that information by running debug.traceTransaction in my local geth instance and parsing the returned JSON. However, I would like to know this information BEFORE I get the returned trace JSON.

Does anyone know an easier way (an API)?

Thanks

Comment: (+1) Hi there - did you solve this problem in the end?

Comment: I did not. AFAIK debug.traceTransaction is the only way to it on live contracts. There are call stack depth tracers available for contracts if you have the Solidity code available to you: https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-stack-depth-lib